# TypeError: sassMiddleware is not a function in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, node-sass

I'm working on an Express.js application and trying to use `sassMiddleware` for compiling SCSS to CSS. However, I'm encountering a TypeError stating that `sassMiddleware` is not a function. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```js
const sassMiddleware = require('sass');
app.use(sassMiddleware({
    src: '/assets/scss/',
    dest: '/assets/css/',
}));
```

I have installed the sass package using npm.
First I was trying to install `npm i node-sass-middleware` but it won't work; later I got to know about the update after 2022 so I installed it with `npm i sass`.
Now it's giving the error:

> TypeError: sassMiddleware is not a function

Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting this error, and how to resolve it? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions.